# Hive map only job/stages creating multiple zero byte file

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql

I have a hive query which has multiple joins , so as number of stages. While executing the query in some scenario, there won’t be any output. In these scenarios the job completes at intermediate stage where the no of mappers is N and no of reducers is 0 ( No reducer) which creates N no of zero byte files

Tried providing the following settings

```
set hive.merge.mapfiles=true 
set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true 
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgfilesize=128000000
set hive.merge.size.per.task=256000000
```

If there is some records in the output we are getting the expected output as per the settings

Basically it happens as a result when no records outputs for a map only job/stage.

I am getting 0byte output as single file if config is set for no of reducers as 1 (all the stage of query uses single reducer )or the compress output as true. Still a 0byte file will be there

A solution would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are running on Tez then add `set hive.merge.tezfiles=true;` And if you are using ORC then use `ALTER TABLE T [PARTITION partition_spec] CONCATENATE; `

Comment: We are running mapreduce with yarn